# Moving the cursor a large number of times in a nnoremap

Tags: vimrc

I have a shortcut in my vimrc to search for a string through my repository:

```
nnoremap <leader>gg :vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist
```

I want the cursor to be between the `//` characters ready for a search term when I invoke the shortcut. I can do this with 18 `<Left>`s but that is very long and ugly i.e.

```
... .py \| clist<Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left><Left>.....
```

I see I can also use `<C-Left>` which is shorter:

```
... .py \| clist<C-Left><C-Left><C-Left><Left><Left>
```

Is there another way to repeat 18  actions without such a long list of `<Left>` in a mapping's definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use counts in a mapping just as you can use them in normal mode. Of course, when you want to use the count you're not *in* normal mode: you're in command-line mode.

A quick hack is to use the command-line window:

```
:nnoremap <leader>gg :vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist<C-F>17<Left><C-C>
```

You can also use `repeat` to create the series of `<left>` keystrokes as a string and `feedkeys()` to "type" this into the command-line. Unfortunately, this... uh... ends up quite a bit more ugly that what you had to start with:

```
:nnoremap <silent> <leader>gg :call feedkeys(':vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist' . repeat("\<lt>Left>", 17))<CR>
```

But an interesting technique nonetheless!

However, probably the cleanest technique — if you want to keep it all in a single mapping — is to set the position of the cursor directly using the `setcmdpos()` function:

```
:nnoremap <leader>gg :vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist<C-R>=setcmdpos(10)<CR><BS>
```

This uses the expression register (see `:help c_CTRL-R_=`) to execute the function: the `<Backspace>` at the end is required to remove the `0` that is entered as the successful result of the `setcmdpos` function.

Comment: Good one! But if you go to the command window, you can do even better with something like `2F/`, which will keep working if you change the command line.

Comment: @filbranden That did occur to me after as I was posting this answer, but I like to keep in the *spirit* of the question :).

Comment: @Rich Thank you. I've gone with the `<C-F>17<Left><C-C>` solution as I like seeing the command: keeping it fresh in the mind when I don't have my vimrc available

Comment: @Rich A cheeky after-question: Would you know why I can't add an extra `\| cc ` on the end? I was also hoping to have a prompt go to the relevant search result by index. This doesn't work as expected:
`nnoremap <leader>gg :vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist \| cc<C-R>=setcmdpos(10)<CR><BS>`

Comment: @NoelEvans That doesn't work because the bar notation `|` will attempt to immediately run the `cc` command (with no argument), whereas you want want to do is emulate *typing* `:cc` so that you can then add an argument. This mapping should have the desired effect: `nnoremap <leader>gg :vimgrep // **/*.py \| clist \| call feedkeys(":cc ")<C-R>=setcmdpos(10)<CR><BS>`

Comment: @Rich Amazing! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This is not a direct answer to *"moving the cursor a large number of times in a nnoremap"* or to *"another way to repeat 18 actions without such a long list of keystrokes in a mapping's definition"*, but it's a different approach to the problem you presented.

Consider creating a new [user-defined command](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) for that operation.

That way, you can have the command-line argument typed by the user be at the end of the line itself.

In your particular example:

```
command! -nargs=1 Pygrep vimgrep /<args>/ **/*.py | clist
nnoremap <leader>gg :Pygrep<space>
```

You'll be left at the command-line, ready to type an argument to `:Pygrep`, which will then be used as search expression for `vimgrep` on your Python files.

Or, if you'd like to preserve the `//` look, to make it clear it's a regexp (and also that you need to escape `/`s):

```
command! -nargs=1 Pygrep vimgrep <args> **/*.py | clist
nnoremap <leader>gg :Pygrep //<Left>
```

You still use a `<Left>` in this case... But it's only a single one.

See [`:help user-commands`](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#user-commands) for more on how to define them.